# How to Facebook Search and Click the first result in Python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to make a script which will be login to facebook and search by a name and click on the first result . I have done almost 90% .

```
from selenium import webdriver
from getpass import getpass
from time import sleep,time

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

usr = input('Enter your username or email id: ')
pwd = getpass('Enter your password : ')
search= "Hasan Mahmud Shojib"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.facebook.com/')

username_box = driver.find_element_by_id('email')
username_box.send_keys(usr)

password_box = driver.find_element_by_id('pass')
password_box.send_keys(pwd)

login_btn = driver.find_element_by_name('login')
login_btn.submit()
sleep(2)

search_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='search']")


search_box.send_keys("Hasan Mahmud Shojib")
search_box.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)


sleep(5)
```

This is the code i have done.It's log in and searching.  It's working . But i can't implement after search and click the first result . can anyone help me to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

The first result (person) can be found by the following css selector:

```
first_person_search_result = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.qu0x051f.f10w8fjw.jb3vyjys')
```